# npm install fails with error C2373 with vs2015 update 3

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, npm, node-gyp

After reinstalling my machine with windows 10, setting it up with `Visual Studio 2015` I encountered this error on installing my git repositories:

→ `npm install` fails on different projects with:

```
...
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\src\win_delay_load_hook.c(34): error C2373: "__pfnDliNotifyHook2": [...]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\...\node_modules\buffertools
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This error stays in relation with `npm`, `node-gyp` and `Visual Studio 2015` and is already fixed in `node-gyp@3.4.0`, but `npm` is still pointing to an old version. As I workaround I can propose this:

1. Go to your folder where npm is installed, e.g.:
   `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm`
2. Open: `package.json`
3. Remove entry for `node-gyp` in `bundleDependencies`
4. Bump version number to `3.4.0` for `node-gyp` in `dependencies`
5. Make a `npm i` in this directory to install `node-gyp@3.4.0` to fix the problem

Relating `GitHub` issues can be found here:

1. [nodejs/node#7286](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7286)
2. [nodejs/node-gyp#956](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/956)
3. [npm/npm#13199](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/13199)
4. [npm/npm#13200](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/13200)

Comment: When you say "Dump entry", do you mean add, or remove?

Comment: I didn't remove it, but the fix still worked. Do I still need to remove it? Thanks! You might want to change the wording of your reply for the benefit any non-native English speakers and ditsy native English speakers.

Comment: It was for sake of completeness

Comment: Note that in a "normal" windows install you will need UAC access to this file, which may require starting an editor and a terminal with the "run as administrator" option, or you won't be able to save the file or run `npm install`

Comment: I've had to also run this to get it working: `npm install -g rimraf`

Comment: Showed some errors in my console but it worked :p windows is so messy

Comment: also, make sure you use windows powershell for the `npm install` or amdinistrator mode because it will fail otherwise

Answer (score 19):

Or update npm:

```
npm install npm -g
```

Comment: Although I like the new output format this gave me, it didn't get rid of the error.

Answer (score 16):

An alternative solution that doesn't involve messing with `npm` installation is to run

```
SET CL=-DDELAYIMP_INSECURE_WRITABLE_HOOKS %CL%
```

before running `npm install`

Comment: Are you issuing the SET command just before running npm install, in the same command prompt instance?

Comment: Yes, I set CL variable before `npm install`, after that another issue was

Comment: Thanks for the tip!
(just had to remove the trailing %CL%)
`
SET CL=-DDELAYIMP_INSECURE_WRITABLE_HOOKS
`

Comment: Using git bash on windows I used `export CL=-DDELAYIMP_INSECURE_WRITABLE_HOOKS` successfully (although my build of `ursa` still failed, node-gyp on windows is a pain)