# React-Native Install Error

Tags: react-native

ling react-native I get the following error (on windows)

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\src\win_delay_load_hook.c(31): 
error C2373: '__pfnDliNotifyHook2': redefinition; different type modifiers
[C:\Projects\JustEatLife\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\ws
\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
```

I've installed windows sdks, added the C++ tools to my VS 2015 installation, installed android studio, java etc.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got same problem, and for me the answer was to update node-gyb from version 3.3.1 to 3.4.0 in npm.

For instructions how to do it, see:

[npm install fails with error C2373 with vs2015 update 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149603/npm-install-fails-with-error-c2373-with-vs2015-update-3)

If `npm i` fails, try `npm install node-gyp` after you have updated version number in packages.json

Comment: This also worked for me. I simplified the steps for updating node-gyp. Just be specific with the version you want. Eg "npm install node-gyp@3.4.0" (in your \Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm dir) lets you skip editing the package.json. You'll see "-- node-gyp@3.4.0  invalid" but "invalid" only means the version isn't what's asked for in the package.json.